# 401 unauthorized streaming spring xd

Tags: twitter, streaming, spring-xd

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples/tree/master/analytics-dashboard

I did the configuration on modules.yml

```
twitter:
  consumerKey: {your-consumer-key}
  consumerSecret: {your-consumer-secret}
  accessToken: {your-access-token}
  accessTokenSecret: {your-access-token-secret}
```

with my own keys and then when i run

```
stream create tweets --definition "twitterstream | log" --deploy
```

this error appear

```
2016-05-24T12:48:07-0500 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR twitterSource-1-1 twitter.TwitterStreamChannelAdapter - Twitter authentication failed: 401 Authorization Required
```

Answer (score 0):

401 error means "Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect". Make sure the credentials is correct. see https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes